# How do I convince gorm it doesn't need to re-create objects it has already created

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, grails-orm

I am using gorm to interact with a Postgres database from a Golang application.

Our database is heavily normalized to make efficient use of space, which means most of the domain level objects in our application are related to one or more other objects.

The structs we have defined often have both a foreign key to other tables as well as a nested version of that foreign object. This is very helpful because when we fetch the top level object from the DB, gorm automatically populates all of its child objects (i.e. when an object references an external type by ID, that type is loaded into our top level object so we don't need to make multiple calls to fetch the data).

The issue is that when we go to create objects in the DB, we end up seeing a lot of unnecessary queries by gorm checking to make sure that we have created these child objects.

I understand how this could be useful, but in many/most cases these foreign keys relate to a table with a small number of objects that is rarely updated. In these cases, when we create our new object that ties into them, we simply populate the foreign key and want gorm to just create our new record without first checking the other table to make sure the object exists.

How do I tell gorm to stop doing this? As a point of reference, one transaction I am trying to do will generate ~300 queries from gorm. When I write the same code using raw sql to do what I want, it takes roughly 100 queries. Most of these extra queries are selects to see if an object exists, or upserts of objects created within the transaction that I already know exist.

I have tried using sessions in gorm, thinking this would cause gorm to cache the objects it creates and know that it doesn't need to query to see if they already exist. This didn't make any difference in the number of queries.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Man, I think that you should be more precise with your question, otherwise you won't get any help! Maybe add a database layout, your Go solution, repro steps, desired goal, and so on. Thanks!